# How do I get List Discussion hierarchy using Sharepoint online 2013 restful interface

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, rest

I am trying to find the hierarchy of Discussions (Items) for displaying

Subject: I have something to sell
    Reply: I'll give you $5 for it
    Reply: I'll give you $5.01

But I can't find anything (reliable) to give me the hierarchy of the replys (reply 1 & 2) both belong to Item.

I am getting my data by constructing my own URIs to get to the items.

```
https://xyz.sharepoint.com/<mysite>/_api/Web/Lists(guid'<hex string')/Items(4)    
Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
```

it returns back a (json_ dictionary of information for the Item.

I have seen mention of ParentID, and somehow using folders.  Neither is what I need (Folders is lists of files...)

I did notice in the Item Body there is  which has a hierarchy (sort of).  But I'm scared to have to parse an html document to get a reliable hierarchy.

So what do I need to be able to get the information I need?

Answer (score 1):

Each item/reply has a "ParentItemID": 1 property. 1 is the original post.
Each original post "ParentItemID": null.

have a query that gets all posts with "ParentItemID": null and then get all reply's with that ID

get all original questions

```
https://{site}/sites/workgroup2/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('DISCUSSIONS LIST')/items?$filter=ParentItemID eq null&$select=ID,ParentItemID
```

then get all items with that ParentItemId

```
https://{site}/sites/workgroup2/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('DISCUSSIONS LIST')/items?$filter=ParentItemID eq 1&$select=ID,ParentItemID
```

Or you can get ALL posts and then process them in JS to create your own array etc

Comment: So yes, that did work.  And I should have seen it.  But, for some reason (<newman>Microsoft...</newman>) didn't correctly populate the ParentItemID for data I had entered previously.  Makes me worry about bugs in <newman>Microsoft...</newman> abilities :(

Answer (score 0):

I had been confronted to that and the parent ID is not the best way. Because if you want to order your answers, if you have answers of answers, and that you delete more than one in a row, you will loose the link between the topic and your answers...

I recommend you to use the ThreadIndex, it's specific to each item (Topics and Replies). You will have a long index (46 characters min.), and there is a logic:

Topics : 46 characters, example:

```
0x01D36467FC1CBE3FDD1E36F74B01BA4CFC96A1F85969
```

And for first answers you will add to this Index 10 random characters, example:

```
0x01D36467FC1CBE3FDD1E36F74B01BA4CFC96A1F8596900000314A9
```

And if you answer to this answer 10 more characters:

```
0x01D36467FC1CBE3FDD1E36F74B01BA4CFC96A1F8596900000314A9000011C2A4
```

And so on, and you can compare each Index because it contains the topic's index and the other answers' index too. This is the only way to keep a hierarchy in every situation even if you delete many answers. Because Sharepoint's developers didn't implement an update on Parent ID when you delete the parent...